# oh my zsh for the root and for all user

Tags: zsh

I have installed `zsh` and I am using Oh My ZSH plugins. Everything works fine, but when I become a root user, it changes to the default zsh theme.

What should I do to make the Oh My ZSH configuration as the default `zsh` for all users including `root`?

I have tried using the `chsh -s /bin/zsh root`

That gave me `zsh` but not `oh_my_zsh`

I also tried `cp -R /home/user/.zshrc /root/.zshrc`ing to get `oh_my_zsh` for root, but nothing worked.

(I don't need `zsh` but I need `oh_my_zsh` for all the user in the system)

Comment: How are you becoming root?

Comment: How did you install *oh my zsh* in the first place? Any why not just do the same for root?

Comment: I think `cFINNY`'s answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193058/1408600 is what you need. I've done that for months on servers i managed. It works for root and all users

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just run the install command as root user (after doing sudo su)

```
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

Answer (score 35):

I made symbolic links to my zsh files in my home dir, that seems to work fine:

```
ln -s $HOME/.oh-my-zsh           /root/.oh-my-zsh
ln -s $HOME/.zshrc               /root/.zshrc
```

Disclaimer (Updated 2020-3-9): Only do this on a single user machine as it will make a user able to run programs as root (see comment by Eliah Kagan).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, eliminates the hustle of installing `zsh` twice.

Comment: If you do that, it actually doesn't make sense to link .oh-my-zsh, because the .zshrc still references the .oh-my-zsh of your original user.

Comment: Didn't work for me when trying to link from non-root to root, ended up installing it for the non-root as well

Comment: I tried it and could not use oh-my-zsh plugins using this method. They were considered insecure by `compinit`.

Comment: I recommend against this method, at least if one does not first consider the security risks. Any program the user runs can edit those configuration files without prompting the user--because they belong to the user, not root--and thus can cause root to perform any action whatsoever next time root uses zsh! *Would you be willing to add (or okay with someone else adding) a warning about that to this answer?*

Comment: This worked for me with one additional step i.e. changing the default shell of root in /etc/passwd e.g.
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/zsh

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi Jee, you're welcome but please notice the comment by Eliah Kagan!

Comment: `ln -s $HOME/.oh-my-zsh           /root/.oh-my-zsh`
`cp -s $HOME/.zshrc               /root/.zshrc `

Comment: how about putting zsh settings in `/etc/zsh/...` and specifying in `/etc/zsh/zshenv` to take the folder from `/etc/zsh`? if you want to edit something there, you must be sudo and that is getting rid of that security issue with symlinks from home users.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else with the same question, I would recommend a combination of Tummala Dhanvi's and Morton's approach. I installed oh-my-zsh both as root and as the user using the following commands:

User:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Root:

```
su
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Then I created a symbolic link for the config file (run as user):

```
sudo ln -s /root/.zshrc $HOME/.zshrc
```

Make sure the user has permissions to read the file:

```
sudo chmod 744 /root/.zshrc
```

This approach allows for a shared config while keeping the system secure. You will, however, need root privileges to edit .zshrc

Answer (score 2):

First install `zsh` or some shell with say `oh-my-zsh` as a normal user.

If you have normally setup the zsh shell & oh-my-zhs framework, then don't just `sudo su` into root & type `chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)` to change shell & framework

First create system links in root of your home shell & framework configs;

- `ln -s $HOME/.zshrc   /root/.zshrc`
- `ln -s $HOME/.oh-my-zsh   /root/.oh-my-zsh`

Then after that go on and change the shell `chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)`

**BUT** if you already changed the shell before making the system links then you will get a return of probably `/root/.zshrc or so file already exists.`

There you have to navigate to the source `/root` & delete whatever existing file they said & then do the system link command required to create it again but sourced from home.

After that you will have a root with the same shell & framework like you have in your normal user's terminal

> *if you have already done all these & it doesn't work because of permission issues, then just grant the permission to these root files;*
>
> - *`sudo chmod 744 /root/.zshrc`*

Answer (score 1):

I installed oh-my-zsh with root account. Now I login with another account, and install oh-my-zsh again in the home directory of the account. It works for the non-root account.

Comment: It doesn't work for me - it tells me that it's already installed in root account (where I initially installed it), and that I need to reinstall it. I suppose that the symbolic link method is the way to go for me. I don't know if it changed since the time of your answer.

Comment: Solution was to remove it from the other user, remove it from the root user, and install it on both, separately.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short script based on Lord Lulent solution, which works well for me

```
USER=barman
USER_HOME_PATH=~$USER
sudo ln -s $HOME/.zshrc   ${USER_HOME_PATH}/.zshrc
sudo ln -s $HOME/.oh-my-zsh   ${USER_HOME_PATH}/.oh-my-zsh
sudo ln -s $HOME/.p10k.zsh   ${USER_HOME_PATH}/.p10k.zsh
sudo chsh -s $(which zsh)  $USER
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help with this use case https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193058/1408600

You could just install for the intended user using:

1. `wget https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh`
2. `su $USER ./install.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to install OhMyZsh for different users.

If it is ok for you to have completely separated settings, you can provide different ZSH paths for each install, like this:

```
ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh" sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The only way that actually works out of all of the above (and seems to be the most natural one):

```
ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh" sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

i.e. you should

1. Assign your user directory's `.oh-my-zsh` path to `ZSH` environment variable
2. Run the regular script